# Gamma function proof

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

I came across this theorem somewhere and it looked really interesting. I don't know how one would go about proving it though? Can anyone give me some pointers? I'd like to understand this statement better.

The statement of the theorem is as follows

> Any function $G$, holomorphic in the right half-plane $\mathbb{C}^+ : 
> \Re(z) > 0$, for which the reduction formula holds
>   $$G(z + 1) = zG(z)$$
>   which decays in any vertical strip as the indeterminate tends to infinity, and such that
>   $G(1) = 1$, *coincides* with the $\Gamma$-function:
>   $$G(z) \equiv \Gamma(z)$$

Comment: What exactly is identity theory?

Comment: I've considered defining a function $Q(z)= \frac{\Gamma(z)}{G(z)}$

Comment: Is that at all helpful?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You statement is exactly: [Wielandt's Theorem About the Γ-Function](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975370?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Answer (score 0):

At this [link](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~web6130/GammaFn.pdf) a found a pretty in depth proof. I think I cannot give anything more that this, the paper explains all in a very intuitive manner.